# how would i go about downloading something from a java application, then putting it in the desktop?

Tags: java, download

hi all well i wan to make an app where it downloads something from a website and puts it in the desktop.

this code downloads it but temporarly, how would i go about saving it?

heres my code

```
    private static void grabItem() throws ClassNotFoundException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException,
        UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    final URL url = new URL("sampleurl");
    final InputStream is = url.openStream();
    final byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();

    // Specify what portion of file to download.
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");

    // Connect to server.
    connection.connect();

    // Make sure response code is in the 200 range.
    if ((connection.getResponseCode() / 100) != 2) {
        logger.info("Unable to find file");
        return;
    }

    // set content length.
    size = connection.getContentLength();
    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        downloaded += length;
        progressBar.setValue((int) getProgress()); // set progress bar
    }
    is.close();
    setFrameTheme();

}
```

thanks

Comment: Why on Earth do you feel the need to throw `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Download. Put the file into the desktop directory. (Or do you mean you want to make it the desktop background?)

Comment: put it in desktop directory

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? Asking `pls help!!` doesn't help you or us any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never write any data at all to your computer... but anyways...

this is how I download & save a file ... it needs to be a direct download but its easy enough to change it to work the way you want it

```
URL url = new URL("direct link goes here");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
```

to get it to save you would then...

```
BufferedOuputStream bufferedoutputstream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("location to save downloaded file")));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;

while((bytesRead = inputstream.read(buffer)))
{
    bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
bufferedoutputstream.flush();
bufferedoutputstream.close();
inputstream.close();
```

that should download & save